# Turbo Pascal 7 DOS {$L sprite01.obj} Как програмно получить размер этого sprite01.obj?

Tags: pascal

Разрабатываю программу. В ней будет графика. Все файлы графики обработаны "BINOBJ sprite01 sprite01.obj SPR01" и вставлены в EXE файл программы `{$L sprite01.obj}`.

Указатель я получаю на SPR01 но не знаю размер данных. Компилировал, смотрел дебагером но нет в ячейках размера ни оригинала ни OBJ файла.

Есть способ получить размер этого OBJ програмно?

Мои варианты решения

1. Я могу создать переменные с размерами всех спрайтов
2. В файл спрайта помещать в начало его размер и перед выводом считывать

Comment: Как вы получаете указатель на спрайт?

Comment: Procedure SPR01;Far;External;    P:Pointer=Addr(SPR01);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Однозначно вариант 2 - в первых байтах хранить общую длину спрайта. Потому, что при изменении размера спрайта вы тут же его и укажете, а и не нужно будет менять основной код программы.

А еще лучше не линковать их, а положить отдельными файлами рядом с программой. Бонусом - уйдете от ограничений 64К на линкуемый файл

Comment: Т.е. под 1 такой спрайт выделяется куча 64к? Они же все будут в куче лежать в одной (64к). Файлы отдельно не хочу :) Потому и спрашиваю. В 64к все поместятся мои спрайты. Я хотел сделать одну картинку, и перед выводом спрайта вырезать как бы область с картинки. Но это долго выполняется =)

Comment: @FrancNet Нет. Линкер не умеет оперировать файлами больше чем 64К. На размещение в памяти это никак не влияет

Comment: У меня уже EXE файл 213 кб. без графики. Есть свободное место до 655350 кб.

Comment: @FrancNet это замечательно. Еще раз **линкер** не может прилинковать файлы, указанные в директиве `{$L ...}`, если размер этих файлов больше, чем 64К

Comment: Ну так спрайты размером 1-5 кб. =)   32х32, есть меньше. до 5 кб. Нет способа програмно получить размер? Я уже и между переменными втыкал и разницу адресов смотрел. TP7 по своему все формирует. Даже код на ASM переделывает на свой лад )

Comment: @FrancNet Нет. Линкуется поток байт

Comment: Нашел как получить размер :) {$L spr1}{$L spr2} помещаются в сегмент кода. Функции Seg и Ofs показывают адреса и смещение. Seg(Spr2)-Seg(Spr1)=Len(Spr1).

Comment: Просто думал что при загрузке OBJ Паскаль где-то хранит размер этих OBJ файлов и их как-то можно получить.

Comment: @FrancNet Только не забудьте завершить все это псевдо-спрайтом, чтобы узнать размер последнего. Ну и молитесь, чтобы компилятор не начал использовать выравнивание

Comment: Да конечно :) Спасибо.

Comment: Ошибок быть не должно т.к. он помещает их в самое начало сегмента кода, первыми идут спрайты а потом код. размер всех спрайтов меньше 64к.

Comment: А можно как-то по другому (не с помощью procedure name;far;external) получить указатель на OBJ файлы? :) мысли дальше пошли ;)

Comment: @FrancNet Если спрайт имеет длину 21 байт, следующий прилинкуется с 22 байта или 24?

Comment: @FrancNet Посмотрите на этот сайт http://turbopascal.org/

Comment: Ну из того что я вижу смещения то 22

Comment: Там на сайте примеры с файлами. Я же хочу спрайты засунуть в EXE. Если на Delphi делать то там уже есть файл ресурсов, который может быть в EXE файле :)

Comment: Запихать в EXE получилось. Теперь как избавится от кучи указателей вида Procedure Name;Far;External; Неужели TP7 помещает OBJ в код и не связывает ни какими связями? В OBJ же есть имя! TP7 думает что это код программы а это данные. Размер не хранит, хотя не факт еще. :)